# How can I use a for loop to run a command over several files with unique output files?

Tags: linux, bash

I need to run a command with the below syntax for 1000 files in a directory and save the output to a unique file for each iteration.

```
command universalinputfile variableinputfile > outputfile
```

for example

```
MotifPSSM ../source/FruR-DPInteract.txt genrand/randomseq_1rndb > motifoutput/output_1

MotifPSSM ../source/FruR-DPInteract.txt genrand/randomseq_2rndb > motifoutput/output_2
```

I've tried using the below for loop without success.

```
for i in {1..1000}
do
        MotifPSSM ../source/FruR-DPInteract.txt genrand/randomseq_$irndb > motifoutput/output_$i
done
```

I've also tried the for loop with the "for file in /dir" format without success.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want `randomseq_${i}rndb` to scope the variable `${i}` ?

Comment: Yes exactly. 

Each input file is named "randomseq_irndb" where i is a number 1 through 1000. I want to run the MotifPSSM command on all 1000 files and have a unique output file for each.

Comment: Try your `for` loop with `${i}rndb`.  Your script had `$irndb` which is totally different; it's looking for a variable called `irndb` instead of a variable `i` followed by `rndb`

Answer (score 2):

`$irndb` is read as a single variable called `irndb`. You can [change the parse to use just `i` as the variable name with `${i}rndb`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
for i in {1..1000}
do
        MotifPSSM ../source/FruR-DPInteract.txt genrand/randomseq_${i}rndb > motifoutput/output_$i
done
```

The `for` loop itself was fine, including the [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) `{1..1000}`, so you don't need to change that.